# Prevent infinite cycle using Mapstruct on parent DTO with a child which has a self reference

Tags: mapstruct

Entities:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "flows")
    public class Flow {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "flow_name")
    private String flowName;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "folder_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Folder folder;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "folders")
    public class Folder {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "internal_id", unique = true)
    private Long internalId;
    @Column(name = "parent_internal_id")
    private Long parentInternalId;
    @Column(name = "project_internal_id")
    private Long projectInternalId;
    @Column(name = "folder_name")
    private String folderName;

    @Column(name="root_flg")
    private Boolean rootFlg;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<Folder> children = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Folder parent;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Project project;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "folder")
    private Flow flow;
```

and DTO's:

```
    public class FlowDTO implements Serializable {
    private final Long id;
    private final String flowName;
    private final Long folderId;
    private final String folderName;
    private final Long parentId;
    private final String parentName;
    private final Long projectId;
    private final String projectName;
    }

    public class FolderDTO implements Serializable {
    private final Long id;
    private final Long internalId;
    private final Long parentInternalId;
    private final String folderName;
    private final Boolean rootFlg;
    private final Long parentId;
    private final String parentName;
    private final Long projectId;
    private final String projectName;
    private final List<FolderDTO> children;
    }
```

and FlowMapper:

```
    @Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
    public interface FlowMapper {
    @Mapping(target="folderId", source="folder.id")
    @Mapping(target="folderName", source="folder.folderName")
    @Mapping(target="parentId", source="folder.parent.id")
    @Mapping(target="parentName", source="folder.parent.folderName")
    @Mapping(target="projectId", source="folder.project.id")
    @Mapping(target="projectName", source = "folder.project.projectName")
    FlowDTO flowToFlowDTO(Flow flow);
    List<FlowDTO> flowsToFlowDTOs(List<Flow> flows);
    @InheritInverseConfiguration
    Flow flowDTOToFlow(FlowDTO flowDTO);
    List<Flow> flowDTOsToFlows(List<FlowDTO> flowDTOs);
```

My problem is Mapstruct doesn't map parentId to parent.folder.id in reverse and this causes an infinite loop while setting parent of folder. Generated mapper Impl is:

```
    protected Folder flowDTOToFolder(FlowDTO flowDTO) {
    if ( flowDTO == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    Folder folder = new Folder();

    folder.setParent( flowDTOToFolder( flowDTO ) ); //this part causes infinite loop
    folder.setProject( flowDTOToProject( flowDTO ) );
    folder.setId( flowDTO.getFolderId() );
    folder.setFolderName( flowDTO.getFolderName() );

    return folder;
    }
```

I thought I can use @BeforeMapping but what is the best practice or a simpler way of doing this.
Any suggestions please? Thnx.

Edit: I added a @Named method like this but didn't work correctly. It gives an error like:
"The type of parameter "flowDTO" has no property named "parent". Please define the source property explicitly."
But target is not "flowDTO", should be "flow"

```
@InheritInverseConfiguration
@Mapping(target="folder.parent", qualifiedByName="parentFolder")
Flow flowDTOToFlow(FlowDTO flowDTO);
List<Flow> flowDTOsToFlows(List<FlowDTO> flowDTOs);

@Named("parentFolder")
@Mapping(target = "id", source = "parentId")
@Mapping(target="folderName", source = "parentName")
Folder flowDTOToParentFolder(FlowDTO flowDTO);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reverse mapping with nested fields is not correctly working, because mapstruct will attempt to re-use any earlier defined methods unless told otherwise.

With the following you can redefine the wanted mapping. (I did not try this out though)

```
    @InheritInverseConfiguration
    @Mapping(target="folder.parent", source=".", qualifiedByName="parentFolder")
    Flow flowDTOToFlow(FlowDTO flowDTO);

    @Named("parentFolder")
    @Mapping(source="parentId", target="id")
    @Mapping(source="parentName", target="folderName")
    Folder flowDTOToFlowParentFolder(FlowDTO flowDTO);
```

Comment: As you suggested I added a name method for specifically for parentFolder mapping, but now gives an error like: "The type of parameter "flowDTO" has no property named "parent". Please define the source property explicitly." . Also updated question with code I changed.

Comment: my bad it should be `folder.parent` instead of `parent`.
Edit: also had the return type wrong as well. fixed that one in the example now also.

Comment: I added a @Named method like this but didn't work correctly. It gives an error like: "The type of parameter "flowDTO" has no property named "parent". Please define the source property explicitly." But target is not "flowDTO", should be "flow"

Comment: Ah I see what I did wrong here, I forgot to add the source parameter. `source="."` or `source="flowDTO"` to the `target="folder.parent", quali....` bit. Editing it to show this.
(sorry for the slow reply)
Edit: Without the `source` argument it will try to find a parent object in the source as well, instead of only in the target.